# Univariate Competing Risk Analysis with R

Tags: r, univariate

I need to carry out a competing risk analysis, and I am using this [paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/bmt2009359.pdf?origin=ppub) as a guide.

The first question: the exp(coef) is the hazard ratio?
The second: how could I carry a univariate analysis (I need a univariate hazard ratio)?
When they use the cbind function, instead of reporting all the variables could I report only one?

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to this forum.

For your first question, you will find it useful to read the article **Practical recommendations for reporting Fine‐Gray model analyses for competing risk data** by Austin and Fine, Stat Med. 2017 Nov 30; 36(27): 4391–4400.  Sections 2.2 and 2.3 of the article will be of particular interest to you as they explain the interpretation of model regression coefficients in a subdistribution hazard model. The article is available at this link: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5698744/.

For your second question, if your sole predictor variable is called **pred** and is continuous or discrete, then you can still construct the design matrix using the syntax **x = cbind(pred)**  and then use it to fit the model:

```
mod <-  crr(FailureTime, Status, x)
```

If your sole predictor variable is categorical, you need to be more careful in how you define your design matrix x.